# convert column type in postgres without losing data

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, type-conversion

How can i convert a `time without time zone` type field to `timestamp without time zone` type field

without losing the data ,

what i tried is creating another timestamp field and copying `time without time zone` values to the `timestamp` field by converting them to the timestamp format , but that too didnt work , any solutions ??

thanks.

**TRY**

```
update mytable set last_updated_att =(select to_timestamp('last_updated_at', 'DD Mon YYYY') from mytable ) ;
```

**last_updated_at : type** :- time without time zone

**last_updated_att : type** :- timestamp without time zone

Comment: I don't think you can convert `time without time zone` to `timestamp without time zone` because the column have only time data, no date is there. SO postgres wont be able to know the date.

Comment: hmm however the reverse is possible i thinnk

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich i think its not possible..because ` time without time zone` field stores only `time` type `timestamp without time zone` needs `date`.>hmm however the reverse is possible i thinnk yes its possible because `timestamp without time zone` have both time and date in filed

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich This can be used to alter the datatype without data loss. `ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN last_updated_att TYPE timestamp without time zone USING time_t::timestamp without time zone;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update 
mytable 
set last_updated_att='today'::timestamp+last_updated_at 
from mytable;
```

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich won't it update all value in the column `last_updated_att` to today?

Comment: Yes i wwas in need to format the values , indeed it places wrong dates

Comment: Since no date is available you have to pick one, I chose `today` because: why not? If you have better information share it in the question.